# Suggested Edits?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I was recently editing a post. However, my edit could not be submitted and the error said

**It has to be a suggested edit."**

What does it mean and does it have something to do with reputation?

**EDIT:** Based on the answers and comments, I would like to add that I edit the posts quite often without any trouble and always it is visible to me only until it is peer reviewed. However, this time, I could not even submit the edit! The system did not accept the edit and threw the above error at me.

Comment: IIRC the expectečd behavior is that after you submit the edit, you see the message: *Thanks for your edit! This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.*

Comment: When I look at your [profile page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/60810/vishal?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), I see that you were able to suggest edits before.

Comment: Have it happened again when you tried to edit something? If it happens again, perhaps you could add a screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible that someone else submitted a suggested edit while you were making yours?

Comment: This has just happened to me. I was changing a question's title only and got the "It has to be a suggested edit" message. When I made a small change to the question body as well, the edit was accepted (pending review). I can provide a screenshot if anyone wants to see it. It also seems that someone else was editing at the same as me so maybe that was it.

Answer (score 2):

You need $2000$ reputation points to be able to edit others' posts. Before you reach that, your edits are considered suggestions and have to be approved by others.

See [Edit Questions and Answers privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: It seems that OP [has been able to suggest edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/60810/vishal?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before.